# Prove for all positive a,b,c that $\frac{a+b}{c}+\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+a}{b} \geq6$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Prove for all positive a,b,c $$\frac{a+b}{c}+\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+a}{b} \geq6$$

**My Try**

I tried taking common denominator of the expression,

$\frac{a^2b+ab^2+b^2c+c^2b+ac^2+a^2c}{abc}$

How to proceed? Is there a way to write them as perfect squares to get the least value? a Hint is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $\frac ac+\frac ca\ge2$ etc.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Why are you answering in a comment?

Comment: Thank you very much @LordSharktheUnknown on point!

Comment: Also follows from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345679/prove-that-fracxy-fracyz-fraczx-geq-3-for-x-y-z0 or  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770341/show-fracbc-fracca-fracab-ge-3-for-a-b-c-0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{c}\geq 6$$ and now use that $$x+\frac{1}{x}\geq 2$$ for all $$x>0$$
You can also use that $$\frac{a^2 b+ab^2+b^2c+c^2b+a^2c+ac^2}{6}\geq \sqrt[6]{(abc)^6}=abc$$

Comment: AM GM method comes handy in inequality solving. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $$\frac{a}{b}+ \frac{b}{c}+ \frac{c}{a} \ge 3 \left( \frac{a}{b} \frac{b}{c} \frac{c}{a}\right)^{1/3}=3~~~~ \mbox{by AM-GM}$$
and $$\frac{b}{a}+ \frac{c}{b}+ \frac{a}{c} \ge 3 \left( \frac{b}{a} \frac{c}{b} \frac{a}{c}\right)^{1/3}=3~~~~ \mbox{by AM-GM}.$$ Adding these two we get the required inequality.
In each case and overall equality occurs when $a=b=c$.

Answer (score 4):

Using Cauchy Schwarz, we can write $\displaystyle (a + b + c) \left(\frac{1}{a} +\frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} \right) \geq 9$. Thus, we have, 
$$ \frac{a+b+c}{a} +\frac{a+b+c}{b} + \frac{a+b+c}{c} \geq 9 \implies 1+ \frac{b+c}{a} + 1 + \frac{a+c}{b} + 1 + \frac{a+b}{c} \geq 9$$
Hence, $$  \frac{a+b}{c}  + \frac{b+c}{a} +  \frac{c+a}{b} \geq 6 $$

Answer (score 3):

If we write $s=a+b+c$ then we have to prove $${s-a\over a}+{s-b\over b}+{s-c\over c} \geq 6$$ or $${s\over a}+{s\over b}+{s\over c} \geq 9$$
or $$s({1\over a}+{1\over b}+{1\over c}) \geq 9$$ or $$(a+b+c)({1\over a}+{1\over b}+{1\over c}) \geq 9$$

or $${a+b+c\over 3}\geq {3\over {1\over a}+{1\over b}+{1\over c}}$$
which is true by Am-Hm for 3 terms.

Answer (score 2):

Using Am-Gm for 6 terms we get: $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{c}\geq 6\sqrt[6]{\frac{a}{b} \frac{b}{a} \frac{b}{c} \frac{c}{b} \frac{c}{a}\frac{a}{c}}= 6$$